# Offers with reservations

Tags: bookings

My client wants a site where registered users can create paid offers of rooms to rent and other users can book those rooms. Users who created offers should be able to see those  reservations.

I think that registered users could create offers as nodes with payment options using the Pay-per-node module. I don't know how to create the booking feature. I tried to use a few modules, but none was proper for my goal.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! As per "I tried to use few modules," you should tell us what you tried, and why the module was not helpful for you. Otherwise, you are probably going to get many modules suggested that you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

There are some useful options, Please note that both Drupal Commerce and Ubercart have Marketplace modules which you could use in combination to achieve your desired functionalities:

A. [Rooms](https://drupal.org/project/rooms) helps with booking and room management, More info also available [here](http://www.drupalrooms.com/)

> Drupal Rooms is a booking and room management solution for hotels,
>   vacation rentals and B&Bs.
>
> It allows an accommodation owner to:

- Create rooms and assign availability (or on hold states) via a
  calendar.
- Manage pricing for rooms using calendars that allow to set pricing for entire seasons or just change it for specific dates.
- Define optional add-ons for rooms. Charge either per-night or per-person. Handle children discounts. Create bookings and keep customer records.
- Make rooms available for booking with a availability
- search functionality and/or calendar - handling both immediate bookings and bookings following owner confirmation.
- Search by Room Type.
- Full integration with Commerce to manage payments, a range of different payment gateways, and a host of other e-commerce features.
- Accept full or partial payments (deposits) using Commerce features.

  B. [Hotel Booking System For Ubercart](https://drupal.org/project/uc_hotel)

> The uc_hotel module is a hotel booking system for Drupal and Ubercart.
>
> It does not manage individual rooms, but rather lets you create room
>   types, and set how many of each type are available for specific dates
>   on the calendar. Each room type can be assigned a different rate, or
>   be based off a single master rate and have a modifier applied to
>   adjust that rate by a certain amount.
>
> You can vary the rate based on the number of adult and child
>   occupants.
>
> The module also features an add-ons and upgrades sub module that
>   allows you to bundle other date-based upgrades with the booking such
>   as tennis lessons or spa treatments.

C. [Open Hotel](https://drupal.org/project/openhotel)

> Open Hotel is a Drupal 7 Distribution that helps you create a full
>   featured Hotel site with online booking and online availability.

**Features**

- Online Availability
- Online Booking
- Multilingual
- Photo Galleries
- Responsive Design
- Google Analytics E-Commerce Integrated
- Free and Open-Source
- Easy to integrate with any payments processor.
- Search Engines Optimized